# Couldnt connect to mongo atlas from the mongo shell, mongo compass and go mgo Driver

Tags: mongodb, mgo, mongodb-atlas, mongo-shell, mongodb-compass

**I'm trying to connect mongo shell with my mongo atlas M0 cluster and ending up getting this error**

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gYgO.png)

**Solution I tried which didnt work:**

*I upgraded the monog version to 4.2 to be insync with mongo version in
atlas, didnt solve the problem getting this error  mongo*

> "mongodb://cluster0-shard-00-02.79t7i.azure.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-00.79t7i.azure.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01.79t7i.azure.mongodb.net:27017/testdatabase?tls=true"
> MongoDB shell version v4.2.8 connecting to:
> mongodb://cluster0-shard-00-02.79t7i.azure.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-00.79t7i.azure.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01.79t7i.azure.mongodb.net:27017/testdatabase?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb&tls=true
>
> *** It looks like this is a MongoDB Atlas cluster. Please ensure that your IP whitelist allows connections from your network.
>
> 2020-08-16T00:14:57.693+0545 E  QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect
> to server cluster0-shard-00-01.79t7i.azure.mongodb.net:27017,
> connection attempt failed: HostUnreachable: Connection reset by peer :
> connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:341:17 @(connect):2:6
> 2020-08-16T00:14:57.695+0545 F  -        [main] exception: connect
> failed 2020-08-16T00:14:57.695+0545 E  -        [main] exiting with
> code 1

**On trying with mgo go driver i'm getting the error as:**

> time="2020-08-17T15:32:32+05:45" level=debug msg="mongo host and port
> :
> mongodb://cluster0-shard-00-00.akidp.azure.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01.akidp.azure.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02.akidp.azure.mongodb.net:27017"
> time="2020-08-17T15:33:32+05:45" level=error msg="Unable to connect to
> mongo no reachable servers" panic: runtime error: invalid memory
> address or nil pointer dereference [signal SIGSEGV: segmentation
> violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x8f3a02]
>
> goroutine 1 [running]: gopkg.in/mgo%2ev2.(*Session).Copy(0x0,
> 0x7fbebca1b008)
> /home/sgupta/go/pkg/mod/gopkg.in/mgo.v2@v2.0.0-20180705113604-9856a29383ce/session.go:1593
> +0x22 github.optum.com/claredi/oti.git/ds.Copy(0xc001ae3a30, 0x0, 0x0)    /home/sgupta/go/src/github.optum.com/claredi/oti.git/ds/ds.go:166
> +0x3c github.optum.com/claredi/oti.git/ds/announcements.indexes()     /home/sgupta/go/src/github.optum.com/claredi/oti.git/ds/announcements/announcements.go:47
> +0xff github.optum.com/claredi/oti.git/ds.Init(0xc0000f8000, 0xc0001efe68)
> /home/sgupta/go/src/github.optum.com/claredi/oti.git/ds/ds.go:98
> +0x52e main.startAPIServer(0x0, 0xc000098360)     /home/sgupta/go/src/github.optum.com/claredi/oti.git/api/main.go:83
> +0xe98 main.main()    /home/sgupta/go/src/github.optum.com/claredi/oti.git/api/main.go:26
> +0x4d exit status 2

Hoping to get a resolution from the experts. Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, in Atlas:

1. Ensure the cluster itself looks healthy in "Clusters"
2. Go to "Network Access" and ensure your IP is allowed
3. Just to be safe, go to "Database Access" and create a new user with proper permissions

If your problem is similar to [Cannot connect to mongodb atlas through mongo shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47958683/cannot-connect-to-mongodb-atlas-through-mongo-shell), it might be that your IP changed or something, and you need to allow your current IP.